# How do (broadcast-only/passive) RFID licence plates assert their identity?

Tags: cryptography, identity, rfid

I would have guessed by some kind of challenge-response, but there seem to be many claims of 'passive' or 'broadcast-only' tags in the plates.

For example from http://www.e-plate.com/security.html:

> [...] the active e-Plate tag is broadcast-only [...] The tag is tamperproof and cannot be used on another vehicle. Optional levels of encryption available. [...] e-Plate conforms to IS024535.

How does this work?  Is it some time-based scheme?  I can't find much information on IS024535 without paying for/ordering it.

Going further, are truly passive tags even possible for identification purposes?  I can't imagine how those would work.  I understand you can do challenge-response if the reader provides the energy to a passive tag, but is that possible at the distances involved in e.g. gantryway identification systems?

Comment: It should be "ISO 24535". Using static response for identification is nothing new. It is based on the assumption that hardware manufacturers would not allow the unique ID to be changed and spoofing requires specialist hardware and knowledge which are expensive to obtain. In either case, the system sounds more secure than a metal plate with writings...

Comment: fingerprints, barcodes, id #s, these are all passive